# Display worldwide search result markers (hundreds/thousands) on map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been tasked with embedding [this search result map](https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=embed&hl=en&q=gym+spa&aq=&sll=49.267805,35.859375&sspn=95.560984,233.964844&ie=UTF8&t=m&st=115179435013108446196&rq=1&ev=zo&split=1&hq=gym+spa&hnear=&ll=46.679594,29.179688&spn=98.0337,233.964844) (i.e. covering the whole world, with little dot markers scattered everywhere) into a web page:

[image: search result map]

but I can't seem to persuade Google Maps to display nearly that many result markers on an embedded map.

### Google Maps "embed" code

The "embed code" HTML that Maps itself gives you via the "link" button is completely unhelpful and just gives me [a single result marker on an otherwise empty map](http://jsfiddle.net/lorddeath/wX3x3/):

[image: broken map]

### Google Maps Embed API

The **Embed API** code gives me [essentially the same thing as the HTML embed code, albeit with more control over zoom](http://jsfiddle.net/lorddeath/YGY3v/):

[image: broken map]

### Google Maps API v3

Switching to the JavaScript API gives me slightly better results, but still a long way from what I'm aiming for.

For example, with the map zoom level set to the whole world, a `radarSearch()` call for the entire bounds of the map gives me [no results and thus an empty map](http://jsfiddle.net/lorddeath/FC2h7/1/):

[image: broken map]

If I zoom in a bit and focus more on the UK (still doing a `radarSearch()` on the whole map bounds), I end up with [a map with a giant mass of markers smothering London, Essex and the East Midlands](http://jsfiddle.net/lorddeath/zCJE5/2/):

[image: broken map]

While if I change from searching in the map bounds to searching within a 50km radius of my arbitrary point somewhere north of Greenwich I get [a similar "drown the Midlands in red" map as I did before](http://jsfiddle.net/lorddeath/3rJD8/2/):

[image: broken map]

Is what I'm trying to do essentially impossible? It seems odd and frustrating that I can't embed into a web page something that Google Maps does as a matter of course...

We've considered using a KML file to store the locations of the pins we want to place (we don't need it to be completely up-to-date or anything), but I'm not sure how I'd go about creating that file in the first place (i.e. exporting the search results I linked to at the top of this post). Is that a possible route or just another dead-end?